# SQL - group by, keep earliest row

Tags: sql, group-by

I have following table:

```
name         team         date
-----------------------------------
John         A-team       02-5-2014
Jessica      A-team       08-6-2015
David        A-team       11-2-2013
Bill         B-team       12-5-2017
Nicole       B-team       18-1-2010
Brandom      B-team       22-9-2012
```

I am trying to create a query which does:

- one row per team, so we groupe on the team
- select that row which happened first, so we are aggregating on min(date)

The following query give the team and the date:

```
select   team, min(date)
from     my_table
group by team
```

But how can I also retrieve the name? I tried following query, but now I get all rows (which I understand, because the grouping does nothing, as all rows are unique now):

```
select   name, team, min(date)
from     my_table
group by team, name
```

Comment: Hint:  Use a `join` to the minimum date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a self join, where you use your first query as sub-query to find each team's first date:

```
select t1.*
from my_table t1
join
  (select team, min(date) min_date
   from my_table
   group by team) t2 on t1.team = t2.team and t1.date = t2.min_date
```

Will return both names if there are two names on a team's first date.

If you just want one row per team, even if that date has two name, you can do another `GROUP BY`, or simply `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t1.*
from my_table t1
where not exists (select 1 from my_table t2
                  where t2.team = t1.team
                    and (t2.date < t1.date
                         or (t2.date = t1.date and t2.name < t1.name))
```

Comment: I didn't think about joining on the same table! Thank you. How can avoid having multiple entries if there are multiple rows which have equal `<team, date>` (but different `name`)?

Comment: Do another group by, use e.g. min().

Comment: @JadeDezo - Then exactly which name need you in this case ?

Comment: Ofcourse! @OtoShavadze I was asking from theoretically point of view. I get it now. THANKS

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for update. Interesting approach with `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(NAME)
    ,team
    ,min(DATE)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY team
```

Comment: I think the question was asking for the name from the same row as the displayed date.  But it's not completely clear.

Comment: @TobySpeight    If you are right, then yes this is not the correct example